# What does !# (exclamation hash), !$:r:r (exclamation dollar colon r), !#:t (exclamation hash colon t) mean in the below bash commands?

Tags: bash, command-history

I have been trying to install a Nagios package and stumbled upon these weird bash expansions on a guide [here](http://samrowe.com/wordpress/advancing-in-the-bash-shell/). Can someone help me understand what do the expansions mean? A wiki link would also be helpful for future reference.

```
root@z:~> wget http://mathias-kettner.de/download/check_mk-1.1.7i5.tar.gz
root@z:~> tar zxvf !#:t
root@z:~> chown -R root:root !$:r:r && chmod -R o-w !$:r:r && cd !$:r:r
root@z:~/check_mk-1.1.7i5> ./setup.sh
```

Comment: If anyone reading this has the rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of the URL linked to in this post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are [`bash` history expansion keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction). They select a line from the shell history and reinsert (portions of) it, possible after modification. The site you linked to does a reasonable job explaining them, but it doesn't describe all of them.

```
tar zxvf !#:t
```

doesn't actually make sense: `!#` selects the line typed so far, but that's `tar zxvf` and we don't want to re-use any of that. It should be

```
tar zxvf !$:t
```

which selects the last portion of the previous line (`!$`), which is the URL given to `wget`, and takes the filename portion (`:t`, for tail — strictly speaking it's whatever's left after the last directory separator, `/`, which happens to work nicely with URLs).

Then

```
chown -R root:root !$:r:r
```

selects last portion of the previous line, drops the file extension (`:r` — strictly speaking, it removes whatever's after the last `.`, including the `.`) twice, which gives the directory name (assuming the tarball contains a directory with the same name as the tarball's base name). The `chmod` and `cd` commands proceed in the same way.