# What is the use of `!#` in csh, bash, zsh and probably other shells?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, csh, history-expansion

From `man bash`:

> `!#`     The entire command line typed so far.

From `man zshall`:

> `!#`     Refer to the current command line typed in so far.  The line is treated as if it were complete up to and including the word before the one with the `!#` reference.

The only thing I could think off is:

```
cd ..;!#!#!#
```

To go up 8 steps:))

Comment: I saw a usage in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283753/231067 but there !# can be replaced with !$ or !* so I don't really consider that a usage

Comment: If you want to really understand why history/bang expansion was invented in `csh` and how their different form are useful, try to use a shell/terminal without any possibility of copy-paste with the mouse or the keyboard and without any line editing capabilities beyond erasing previous stuff from the line (no going back and forth, neither with the arrows nor with `hl`). FWIW, `!#` doesn't seem to be documented in the original `csh`, only in `tcsh`, and is kind of buggy in `csh` (`echo x !#` will result in `echo x echo x echo`; your `cd` example also doesn't work because of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use it often but it's sometimes useful in conjunction with `:`
for extracting n-th word of the command. For example:

```
$ touch FILE.a
$ echo file created
$ mv FILE.a !#:1.bak
mv FILE.a FILE.a.bak
```

Another example, although quite pointless in practice, would be using
it together with `cut` to get contents of the variable defined in the
same line in the simple command, for example:

```
$ LETTER=a echo letter: $(cut -d '=' -f2 <<< "!#:0")
letter: a
```

Notice that this wouldn't work as `$LETTER` is expanded before running
the command:

```
$ LETTER=a echo letter: $LETTER
letter:
```

Comment: I could use `!$`, or just `Alt-.` but only if I typed `mv` command
just below `touch`. In practice I would use [dabbrev-expand in xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139016/72304)

Comment: Can you elaborate on Alt-.?

Comment: Read explanation of `yank-last-arg` in `man bash`.

Comment: The mv example can be writting using brace expansion: `mv FILE.a{,.bak}`